# Gson omits hours when parsing Joda DateTime object

Tags: java, android, json, gson, jodatime

I have a Joda `DateTime` field in the object I receive from the server. For example, the field value is `2016-09-01T11:30:00.000+03:00`. Then, when calling `gson.toJson()`, the field is converted into a date-only string, `2016-09-01`.

Code:

```
final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeSerializer());
final Gson gson = builder.create();
String str = gson.toJson(response.body());
```

When debugging I noticed that my custom type adapter's `serialize` method is not called. Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly, but I was expecting the method to be used when converting object to JSON string (on the other hand, `deserialize` is called when using `gson.fromJson()` on a string).

This is the custom type adapter:

```
public class DateTimeSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<DateTime>, JsonSerializer<DateTime>
{
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.date();

    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(final JsonElement je, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
        final String dateAsString = je.getAsString();
        return dateAsString.length() == 0 ? null : DATE_FORMAT.parseDateTime(dateAsString);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final DateTime src, final Type typeOfSrc,
                                 final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src == null ? "" : DATE_FORMAT.print(src));
    }
}
```

Any idea why is it parsed this way and how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Well you're explicitly using `ISODateTimeFormat.date()`, which *is* only going to be date rather than date/time. So I'm not surprised that it's losing time information. Admittedly the failure to call `serialize` is worrying...

Comment: Silly me... was investigating the `serialize` part and didn't notice that I'm using `date()` instead of `dateTime()`. This solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, I was using `ISODateTimeFormat.date()` instead of `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()`.